# Nginx в Docker-контейнере показывает только стартовую страницу

Tags: php, nginx, docker

С помощью `docker-compose up` запускаю вот такой конфиг:

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - /home/ilya/projects/main:/code
        - /home/ilya/projects/main/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
        - php
        - mysql

php:
    # docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql --- need exec this
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - /home/ilya/projects/main:/code
    links:
        - mysql

mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment: 
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
        - mysql:db
    ports:
        - "8082:80"
    environment:
        - PMA_USER=root
        - PMA_PASSWORD=pass
        - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=100MB
```

Все затем, в каталог с проектом помещают вот такой конфиг Nginx'a:

```
server {
    index index.php;
    server_name dune.com pro.dune.com;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Все работает нормально, но открывается только стартовая страница. При попытке открыть любую другую:

> 404 Not Found

Как нужно поправить конфиг nginx'a, чтобы открывались URL вида dune.com/hello?

Comment: `location /` прописать

Comment: Если у вас одна входная точка, то вставьте примерно такое: location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Suvitruf и Maksim Fedorov, проблема была действительно в `location /`.

Просто добавил:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args; 
}
```

И все заработало.